# How do I know what type of .PLIST file I am opening?

Tags: file, plist, broken-links

I am trying to open a .PLIST file, but I don't know what type of .PLIST file it is.

I know there is Binary, XLM and ASCII, But when I open mine in an XML or even an .PLIST reader, it ends up like this:

‘^ŕ•}Ě™ŕ~Gĺ‰€‡®îo/<|ÉÇ·‹qůćĆŔŢ! “ç7yű€p”öăŐ­Ëtű¤¬„Ť˙+}yLśqŁŐq6Şže»ź÷K’ź»ucÍ#«Ý˛Ţrľżß–­tśűLÍm§zÝů§rk‰ň 2Ąßt«°iŘM”#NkăÖ×ěÜgŚŮńéNČŻAĚóÉŹĘčĆ‡őíEĐŃŮ–!ŃňÂ˘›
ĹC?ĎŹşťăíáŽyÜĚaż˘»4úď!“`ĹëŐu”yŹŻt_ś­Q,HÉ÷.—s
_­qĐ’Ä”‘w„·9‰”  ‡í4ńfŮcÎ5eA¸$AŔpĺ•UĐ8óhŮ2ć—»ťßžV-,C°$6ŤA‚Ľś¶nłÔă†‰µ ~ý$9ů˙>Ë  Žůőćp=ş$j"ż\ýX˛yÂ‰řÁšd

How do I know if I am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the command file. File is the standard unix program for the recognition of data.

On your linux machine :

Open a terminal
Type “file” myfile
You should have in the output the exact type of data